# Adding controls dynamically with x:Name in MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

In our WPF application, we have a lot of forms with fixed fields. Every form should now be extended with fields the user can define himself. The database contains a table with these user defined fields, each with a label, a type (text, date, numeric, ...), etc.

I have found a lot of great solutions using DataTemplates, there is one issue with this however: **it is not possible to generate a unique `x:Name` property for each field** (using the field id for example).
Our application relies heavily on the `x:Name` property to do things as: show/hide fields, set a mask on numeric fields, move fields, ... All this functionality is read from the database, so a unique identifier per field is needed.

One solution would be to generate these fields with the `x:Name` in the codebehind (the Winforms way).
Another solution would be to change the functionality that uses the `x:Name` to using the `Tag` property.

Before I implement one of these solutions, I want to make sure there is no better way. Is there an MVVM way to dynamically generate fields with an x:Name?

**Edit**

There seems to be some confusion as to why I would need an `x:Name` for my fields in an MVVM scenario, so I'll clear it up with an example:

One requirement of our software is that *every* form field in our application can be set hidden or visible by the user. I'm talking about thousands of fields here. I could have created an property for every field that contains the visibility status and fill it from the database.

Instead, I have created an attached property (attached once in a style) that retrieves the visibility status based on the name of the field and apply it. So this functionality runs separately from the MVVM architecture (I never use the `x:Name` in the `ViewModel`). The disadvantage of using the attached property is that the form fields need an identification, being the `x:Name` property in my case.

Comment: It seems like your MVVM approach might be broken if you heavily rely on the `x:Name` property to do things . In MVVM you usually don't want to have your `ViewModel` know about the `View` or directly interact with it. (E.g.: see discussion here: [How to use x:name from view in viewmodel](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ddb357a9-0d41-467a-b997-8aaa7c3566a9/how-to-use-xname-from-view-in-viewmodel?forum=wpf))

Comment: What kind of logic is dependent on the `x:Name` ? And where is it placed in the code behind?

Comment: Actually, the `ViewModels` never use the `x:Name` directly. It is used by `Attached Properties` to be able to uniquely identify a field. Example: a form contains 10 numeric fields. The user can determine in the database for each field what the input mask is (eg: #6.2 for the first textbox, #3 for the rest). In this case, I see no other way than to store the `x:Name` in the database.

Comment: Do you use numbers for `ID` column in the database for your fields? If Yes, it would be possible for you to use the `ID` column in your database to become an invisible (don't use) property on the UI and the underlying viewmodel would store instances of your UI model along with the ID.
This would discard the need to generate unique names, perhaps?

Comment: We are currently using strings to identify our fields. However, the problem probably remains the same: you are talking about an _invisible (don't use) property_. Currently this is the `x:Name` property but could also be the `Tag` property as I suggested. They would both be used to identify the field, the only difference is the `Tag`can be bound to.

Comment: So essentially the problem is about having a `Name` like field on the UI control , which can be bound to. An easy option is the `Tag`. However, should there be a need of multiple such properties in future you might want to consider extending the UI controls to have custom dependency properties which can be bound to, from the VM

Comment: @bit: That is exactly my problem and if there is no other way, I will use the `Tag` field instead. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @BrunoV you should look at tutorials and fix your obvious lack of knowledge about how to solve things in an MVVM way instead of using the Tag property...

Comment: @Dbl: Well I'm here to learn and I have added an example to my question as to why we are using the `x:Name` property. Maybe you can help me with a better way of solving my problem.

Comment: @BrunoV Sure. You'll have to provide the very basic essentials of how your code works though. Because what you are describing sounds like something which can be easily solved without any usage of attachedproperties and x:Name

Comment: You could always iterate through the fields after binding (use the Dispatcher to schedule this operation at the appropriate priority) to examine each DataContext and then assign a name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an MVVM way to dynamically generate fields with an x:Name

No, there isn't.

`x:Name` is a *XAML* directive that is used to uniquely identify a UI element in a XAML namescope and generate a backing field to store the value in the code-behind class of the view.

The view model doesn't and shouldn't know anything about this and it should certainly not generate such elements or backing fields as this would break everything that the MVVM pattern is all about.

If you do require to generate unique names for your UI elements for some reason, you should implement this functionality in the code-behind of the view.

MVVM is not about eliminating view-related code from the views, it is mainly about separation of concerns and testability.